# Alternative to gRPC that uses websockets?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, grpc

I'm in the middle of a very large project to migrate my application from Java to JavaScript, and am trying to decide what the messaging protocol should be for client/server. Some notes on what I'm looking for:

1. There is a very large amount of data streamed from the server to client, with infrequent small requests made from the client to server (responses may be large). Network performance is a **very** big concern.
2. We are going to deploy the new JS-based client primarily in an Electron container, but with support for "modern" browsers in the future (no ETA for that requirement, but I also don't want to be scrambling when it becomes mandatory).
3. The server side is and will remain in Java.
4. Need good backward compatibility options, as we will not always be able to control the client versions.

The research we've done so far has indicated gRPC (with ProtoBuf) as a strong candidate that ticks all the boxes. The grpc package seems to work great in Electron, and the server coding in Java is very easy. The biggest downside is that, since it uses HTTP/2, we have to jump through hoops to run it in a browser (grpc-web combined with a data proxy).

Are there any good alternatives that use websockets, or other suggestions entirely? Ideally we would like to use the same code when executing in Electron vs. browser.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [WAMP protocol](https://wamp-proto.org/).  The lead implementation is [Autobhan](https://crossbar.io/autobahn/).  It's an RPC & PUB/SUB client-server framework that works by exchanging JSON (or msgpack) messages over websocket.  So fits in well with Javascript and browser side.